# Node Error: URL redirected too many times

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, express, https

I am trying to redirect all HTTP traffic to go to HTTPS but keep getting a "redirected too many times" error. It works fine on local machine but I get this error when I go to URL using AWS server.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
  return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
}
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + pathToUse + '/html/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Try `req.originalUrl` instead of `req.url`, maybe it will help. And try to debug, add some console.log's to your middleware.

Comment: Are you connecting directly to the server, or is there an ELB in the mix?

Comment: @LukeWaite There is an ELB

Answer (score 1):

I was using an ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) and the following code worked:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if((!req.secure) && (req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https')) {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```